# How to create child objects inside parent list through partial ASP.NET MVC 4 views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

After Googling a bunch, I'm still stuck on this problem. I'm pretty new on Asp.Net MVC things

Say you have those model classes:

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SthElse { get; set; }
        public List BarList { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SthElse { get; set; }
        public Foo ParentFoo { get; set; }
    }
```

Here I have individual controllers to Foo and Bar with a scaffolded Create ActionResult method on both. On the Foo Create view, I need to add some Bar objects with a modal form and show added Bar objects like on [this](http://twitpic.com/1937o4/full) example.

The [ASP.NET Music Store Example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store) only covers the case where you have previously inserted objects (you couldn't create Artist, Genre and Album at the same view, I.E.: Imagine an "Add new Music CD" use-case where you need to be able to create a new Artist, a new Genre at the same view where you create an Album). How do I could accomplish that using modal views?

Could you point me a tutorial or else that covers this scenario (Create a new Foo and Bar children at the same view)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you need to create a view model by combining these two models

Comment: yes, but Does the Bar Create view needs to be partial?

Comment: Do you mean you want to create tabbed layout? as of the picture in the link you've posted?

Comment: yes, but for each tab I want to add CRUD operations, I.E.: I want to be able to freely add/remove/update "Covered Devices" using a modal window form, like we have on some Single Page Applications out there.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy.

Model

```
public class FooBar {
    public Foo Foo {get;set;}
    public Bar Bar {get;set:}
}
```

Controller

```
public class FooBarController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index() {};
    public ActionResult Edit(FooBar model)
    { 

    }
}
```

View:

```
@model FooBar

@using(Html.BeginForm) {
    @EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
    @EditorFor(x => x.Bar)
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering @erik-funkenbusch. But the case is a parent-child relationship, where Foo have a list of Bar objects, and not a composition of Foo and Bar solely.

Comment: Imagine the Contoso University Asp.Net MVC 5/EF6 Example from [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc). The issue is: I wanna be able to Add a new Student and assign course enrollments for this Student at the same page.

Comment: @CezarLamann - you just add them to your lists as part of the creation or edit process